# Axiom of union - singleton case

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I have a question concerning the axiom of union. We know that the axiom states that given a set $A$, there is a set $U$ which contains all elements of the elements of $A$. It is clear that if $A=\lbrace \lbrace 1, 2\rbrace, \lbrace 2, 5, 6\rbrace \rbrace$, then $U=\lbrace 1, 2, 5, 6\rbrace$. Now, what happens if $A=\lbrace 7\rbrace$? We would have $U=\lbrace x | \ \exists a\in A, x\in a\rbrace=\lbrace 
 x | x\in 7\rbrace=...?$. I know that 7 is also considered as being a set in the axiomatic theory, but I don't understand how do we conclude who $U$ actually is in this case.

Comment: What is the union of $\{A\}$?

Comment: I think it depends on who is $A$. If $A=\emptyset$, then $\cup\lbrace A\rbrace=\emptyset$. That's exactly what my trouble is. What happens when $A=7$? Intuitively, I would say that the union is: $\cup\lbrace A\rbrace=\cup\lbrace 7\rbrace=\lbrace 7\rbrace$, but I don't know how to explain this in axiomatic terms.

Comment: I don't see how the content of $A$ are relevant here.

Comment: So, you're saying that $\cup\lbrace 7\rbrace$ is the emptyset? Not sure why this would be true...

Comment: I have no idea where you think I said that. I simply said that the content of the set $A$ is irrelevant to the question what is $\bigcup\{A\}$.

Comment: If you say that the content of A is irrelevant, you are actually saying that the answer is the same and it does not depend on $A$. At least, that's how I get your answers. :)

Comment: No, that is not at all what I am saying. The answer to "what is in your lunch box?" is irrelevant to the question "is this your lunch box?". The content of $A$ is irrelevant to the answer what is $\bigcup\{A\}$. The answer will depend on $A$, but its content is irrelevant.

Comment: All right! Then, the answer would be $\cup\lbrace 7\rbrace=7$.

Comment: The "set $U$ which contains all elements of the elements of $A$" is not denoted by $\cup\{A\}$ but $\cup A.$ E.g. $\cup\{X,Y\}=X\cup Y,$ $\cup\{X\}=X,$ $\cup\varnothing=\varnothing.$